# Automatical deploying to Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a question about the automatically deploying from Eclipse to Glassfish. When I add the project to Glassfish I can choose whether or not to automatically deploy it. When I have the setting on and save a file I am working on the file is deployed. Is this a plugin or is it something Eclipse and Glassfish has a default option? I am new to the Java EE 6 and Maven.. And it isn't Maven that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by [Glassfish Tool for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-bundle-eclipse), which is an Eclipse Plugin. The tool doesn't include Glassfish Runtime, one have to install that separately.

Comment: Does it build the whole archive each time then?

Comment: @vkraemer: Thanks for the info. Would you be able to provide some resource to confirm this, as I did search the web hard, but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the 'Edit Application' page for an app that you deployed from inside Eclipse.  You will see something like "Location: ${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/eclipseApps/test3/"... if you go to that location (~/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/test3 for me) you will see the directory contains the exploded content of your app.

Comment: @vkraemer: But that doesn't mean anything. Well, try to change, say one of your JSPs, directly there, using some external editor. Then don't build your project and try to access that. You might not able to access that because of invalidity of your contents according to the original `.war` deployed. Or your page may get replaced with the one present in `.war`. However, the best way to test this is to check out the timestamp of `.war`/`.ear`, upon saving a resource.

Comment: That would be another way to check it...  Remember, the web does not have direct answers to all questions, sometimes you have to trust the answers of folks that wrote or maintain the code.